# Can anybody explain what that expression does?

Tags: javascript

I stumble on a part of code, I don't understand and don't know how to research as well. A simplified version of it is as follows:

```
    var obj = {
            token: 'asdfasdfaksjdfk23432',
            userId: '1q2w3e4r',
            test: true
        },
        obj1 = {
            token: 'asdfasdfaksjdfk23432',
            userId: '1q2w3e4r',
            test: false
        };
    if((obj = obj1).userId){
        console.log(true);
    };
```

Just wondering, what does the `(obj = obj1)` part means|does.

Comment: It assigns `obj1` to `obj`, and then uses that to check its `userId` property.

Comment: Where exactly did you find this code, can you link the whole thing? What other parts are there, where else is the `obj` variable used and how?

Comment: It basically just breaks there (switch|case issue).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a *very confusing* way of

(1) assigning `obj1` to `obj` (discarding whatever `obj` happened to have previously)

(2) Checking whether `obj1.userId` is truthy or not

Assignments resolve to an expression, unfortunately. It's equivalent to:

```
obj = obj1;
if (obj1.userId) {
    console.log(true);
}
```

(note that the `if` block should not have a `;` after its last `}`. For that matter, it shouldn't be evaluating the assignment as an expression either, but that's the whole question...)

Comment: "*unfortunately*" - if they didn't, we couldn't write things like `a = b = 0;`

Comment: Guess it's opinion-based - I don't like seeing that either, it makes me wonder if it's *really* supposed to assign both variables to 0, or if it was a typo and it was an attempt at comparison instead

Comment: sorry, that was my typo. it's already automatic reaction to add ```;``` at the end of line :D

Answer (score 1):

I think you will find that this is assigning the values inside the if statement. This is not super clear and you should probably not do this.

For example your code is the same as:

```js
var a = 4;
var b = 10;

if (a = b) {
  // Will output 10, 10 because it sets a to b.
  console.log(a, b)
}
```

This is because it will run a = b setting the value of a to b.

A better solution would be to  declare this prior to the if statement for clarity.

Hope that helps.